# Which release is stable?

Tags: apache-flink

i am trying to play with apache-flink, with the set of examples and i am trying to compile them from scratch using GitHub code in order to run them using the flink install from brew command.

It's funny but the brew installation does not include any of the examples, so I am forced to install them from the sources in GitHub.

The problem is i cannot compile the examples because of some errors. I understand that this compiling error can happen, i only need one stable branch to run the projects as described in [the official link](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.5/quickstart/setup_quickstart.html).

I am using this settings:

```
java -version
java version "1.8.0_172"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_172-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.172-b11, mixed mode)

mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.5.0 (ff8f5e7444045639af65f6095c62210b5713f426; 2017-04-03T21:39:06+02:00)
Maven home: /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.5.0/libexec
Java version: 10.0.1, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-10.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home
Default locale: es_ES, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.13.4", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

This is the [link](https://pastebin.com/xsB5bJXn) of release-1.5 compile.

This is the [link](https://pastebin.com/yUXp8WF8) of release-1.3 compile.

This is the [link](https://pastebin.com/PQW0SiZF) of master compile.

Which release is stable?

EDIT

After @FabianHueske advice, i downgraded the maven version:

```
flink aironman$ mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.2.5 (12a6b3acb947671f09b81f49094c53f426d8cea1; 2014-12-14T18:29:23+01:00)
Maven home: /usr/local/Cellar/maven@3.2/3.2.5/libexec
Java version: 10.0.1, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-10.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home
Default locale: es_ES, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.13.4", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
MacBook-Pro-Retina-de-Alonso:flink aironman$ jenv versions
system
1.7
1.7.0.51
1.8
1.8.0.172
10.0
10.0.1
oracle64-1.7.0.51
* oracle64-1.8.0.172 (set by /Users/aironman/.jenv/version)
oracle64-10.0.1
MacBook-Pro-Retina-de-Alonso:flink aironman$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_172"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_172-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.172-b11, mixed mode)
```

This is the [output](https://pastebin.com/gm5eaJsm) of the compiling of the tag release-1.5.0.

I realize that maven is trying to use version 10.0.1 of the jdk, although the command java -version says I'm using version 1.8, it might be a problem with my maven and jdk configuration?

Comment: The website of the Flink project answers that question: http://flink.apache.org/downloads.html

Comment: Well, it is not true that release-1.5 is stable. Not compiling!

Comment: The `release-1.5` branch is the development branch for the 1.5.x release line. The tag `release-1.5.0` points to the code of the Flink 1.5.0 release. Also your Maven version might be an issue. Try building with Maven 3.2.5 as noted in the [documentation](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.5/start/building.html).

Comment: Thank you @FabianHueske, I am updating the thread with new info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only compile Flink with java 8, according to the exceptions during the build you're using java 9+.